# Jsoup.connection Throws error

Tags: android

I want to parse html pages and extract data but when I tried to connect with Jsoup it throws errors. when I connected using httpclient [String s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");] there was no problem the html page content I was able to store into a string. But with Jsoup I am not able to do it.Am I making some error?
package com.example.flashcardsdemo;

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

//import com.example.flashcards.MainActivity.Gethtml;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context=this;
        Gethtml Ght = new Gethtml();
        Ght.execute();
    }

    public class Gethtml extends AsyncTask {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        String UrlLink = "http://en.wikipedia.org/";
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Loading");
            dialog.setMessage("Html....");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(UrlLink);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                StatusLine line = response.getStatusLine();
                int statuscode = line.getStatusCode();
                if (statuscode != 200) {
                    return null;
                }

                Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(UrlLink).get();

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("Error", e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }   
}
```

LogCat image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6bDv.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBxUB.png

Answer (score 0):

I found "NoClassDefintionFound" error for Jsoup from logcat.

Got to Java build path of your android project >> Order and Export tab >> Check your Jsoup library.
After checking the Jsoup library , select it and move it up using UP button.

Then clean the project and run it again.